# Tailwind css responsive grid not working consistently. (ReactJs)

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a responsive site using Tailwind CSS in React.
Tailwind Version: 3.3.3

```js
function Accordion(){
  const themeClass = !darkMode
    ? "self-stretch text-lg p-3 items-center h-full bg-gray-200 drop-shadow-md mt-2.0 border-2 rounded-xl grid grid-rows-4" +
      " airportAccordionSm:grid-cols-3 airportAccordionSm:grid-rows-2" +
      " airportAccordionMd:grid-cols-4 airportAccordionMd:grid-rows-none"
    : "self-stretch text-lg p-3 items-center h-full bg-gray-500 drop-shadow-md mt-2.0 border-2 rounded-xl grid grid-rows-4" +
      " airportAccordionSm:grid-cols-3 airportAccordionSm:grid-rows-2" +
      " airportAccordionMd:grid-cols-4 airportAccordionMd:grid-rows-none";

   return (
    <div className="align-baseline">
      <div className={themeClass}>
        <div
          className="text-center row-start-1 row-end-2
                airportAccordionSm:col-start-1 airportAccordionSm:col-end-2 airportAccordionSm:row-start-1 airportAccordionSm:row-end-2
                airportAccordionMd:col-start-1 airportAccordionMd:col-end-2 "
        >
          <div
            className={
              darkMode ? "text-gray-100 font-bold" : "text-gray-500 font-bold"
            }
          >
            ICAO/IATA
          </div>
          <div className="contrast-500">{icaoAndIata}</div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="text-center row-start-2 row-end-3
                airportAccordionSm:col-start-2 airportAccordionSm:col-end-3 airportAccordionSm:row-start-1 airportAccordionSm:row-end-2
                airportAccordionMd:col-start-2 airportAccordionMd:col-end-3 "
        >
          <div
            className={
              darkMode ? "text-gray-100 font-bold" : "text-gray-500 font-bold"
            }
          >
            Name
          </div>
          <div className={darkMode ? "text-gray-100" : "text-gray-500"}>
            {station.name}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="text-center row-start-3 row-end-4
                airportAccordionSm:col-start-3 airportAccordionSm:col-end-4 airportAccordionSm:row-start-1 airportAccordionSm:row-end-2
                airportAccordionMd:col-start-3 airportAccordionMd:col-end-4  "
        >
          <div
            className={
              darkMode ? "text-gray-100 font-bold" : "text-gray-500 font-bold"
            }
          >
            Location
          </div>
          <div className={darkMode ? "text-gray-100" : "text-gray-500"}>
            {station.city}, {station.region.region_name},{" "}
            {station.country.country_name}
          </div>
        </div>
        // The issue the here
        <div
          className="text-center row-start-4 row-end-5
                airportAccordionSm:col-start-2 airportAccordionSm:col-end-3 airportAccordionSm:row-start-2 airportAccordionSm:row-end-3
                airportAccordionMd:col-start-4 airportAccordionMd:col-end-5"
        >
          <Link
            className={
              darkMode
                ? "rounded-lg bg-green-400 py-1 px-3 hover:bg-yellow-300 hover:no-underline text-gray-100"
                : "rounded-lg bg-green-400 py-1 px-3 hover:bg-yellow-400 hover:no-underline"
            }
          >
            Go to Airport
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

I use custom responsive sizes like `airportAccordionMd` and `airportAccordionSm`.

Starting with a grid with 4 rows, `airportAccordionSm` will switch to 3 columns and 2 rows, `airportAccordionMd` will switch to 4 columns without any rows.
The issue is `airportAccordionMd`.

Starting:[image: Staring Size]

airportAccordionSm Size:[image: sm size]

Issue is here, airportAccordionMd Size:[image: airportAccordionMd size]

The grid will not change from 3 columns 2 rows to 4 columns only. For somehow the new grid just won't apply:
[image]

However, If I add this in between the grid:

```js
  <div className=" text-center airportAccordionMd:col-start-4 airportAccordionMd:col-end5">
       TEST TEST TEST
  </div>
```

This will work:
[image: Test]

I put the code into the sandbox but it won't work properly, I deleted some props and hooks but this is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-grass-kqdm4q?file=/src/AirportAccordion.js